# Find $\int\sqrt{(x-2)/(x-1)}\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am having difficulty with these type of problems.

Can anyone explain how to approach the problems of the form $\int \sqrt{\dfrac{x-a}{x-b}}\hspace{1mm}dx$

Comment: You can rationalize the integrand by substituting $u = \sqrt{\frac{x - a}{x - b}}$, then apply partial fractions, then integrate each term separately. If you run into trouble, say so and I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Use the substitution $x=a \sec^2 \theta + b \tan^2 \theta$

Answer (score 4):

Let us consider the integral
$$I=\int\sqrt{\frac{x-a}{x-b}} dx$$ and, to get rid as soon as possible of the square root, make a change of variable such as $$\frac{x-a}{x-b}=y^2$$ that is to say $$x=\frac{b y^2-a}{y^2-1}$$ which gives $$dx=\frac{2 y (a-b)}{\left(y^2-1\right)^2}dy$$ Back to the integral, we then have now $$I=(a-b)\int \frac{2 y^2 }{\left(y^2-1\right)^2} dy$$ The integrand can now be decomposed using partial fractions and $$\frac{2 y^2 }{\left(y^2-1\right)^2}=-\frac{1}{2 (y+1)}+\frac{1}{2 (y+1)^2}+\frac{1}{2 (y-1)}+\frac{1}{2 (y-1)^2}$$ which involves simple integrals and, as a final result $$\int \frac{2 y^2 }{\left(y^2-1\right)^2} dy=\frac{y}{1-y^2}+\frac{1}{2} \log (1-y)-\frac{1}{2} \log (1+y)=\frac{y}{1-y^2}-\tanh ^{-1}(y)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 2):

For the integral in your title you can substitute
$$x-1=\cosh^2\theta\ ,\quad x-2=\cosh^2\theta-1=\sinh^2\theta\ ,\quad
  dx=2\cosh\theta\sinh\theta\,d\theta\ .$$
Then you get
$$I=\int\frac{\sinh\theta}{\cosh\theta}2\cosh\theta\sinh\theta\,d\theta
   =\int2\sinh^2\theta\,d\theta=\int(\cosh2\theta-1)\,d\theta$$
which is now a standard integral.  The generalisation can be done in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x-1=\sec^2 u$ so that $dx=2\sec^2u   \tan u  \ \ \text{and } x-2=\sec^2 u-1$ this shows that $$\int\sqrt\frac{x-2}{x-1}\,dx=2\int \tan^2 u\sec u\, du=2\int (sec^3 u- \sec u)\, du.$$ know, for $2\int sec^3 \, du$ use the Integration by parts formula  and  $2\int \sec u\, du= \ln|\sec u+\tan u|+C$

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the integral as

$$\int\sqrt{1-\frac1{x-1}}dx$$

Similar to other trigonometric substitutions, one could eliminate the square root with a trigonometric substitution

$$\frac1{x-1}=\sin^2t,x-1=\csc^2t,dx=-2\csc^2t\cot tdt$$
$$\int\sqrt{1-\frac1{x-1}}dx=\int-2\csc^2t\cot t\sqrt{1-\sin^2t}dt=\int-2\csc t\cot^2tdt=$$
$$\int-2\csc^3tdt+\int2\csc tdt$$

I'm sure you've handled similar integrals with secant.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by differentiation that
\begin{align*}
\int\sqrt{\frac{x-a}{x-b}}\,\mathrm dx=\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}+(b-a)\ln\left(\sqrt{x-a}+\sqrt{x-b}\right).
\end{align*}
Of course, one has to careful to define the integrand for only such $x\in\mathbb R$ that $x\neq b$ and $(x-a)/(x-b)\geq0$